# Reading in input file with strings and doubles separated by commas and multiple lines. C++

Tags: arrays, input, char, double, strtok

How can I read an input file that has strings and doubles separated by commas with multiple lines.  I want to keep the strings in a multidimensional array like char Teams[5][40] 
For examples the file is something like:

```
Team1,0.80,0.30
Team1,0.30,0.20
Team1,0.20,0.70
Team1,0.70,0.80
Team1,0.90,0.20
```

I was thinking about using **strtok** but I'm not sure how to iterate throughout everything and all the lines while making keeping the doubles assigned to their string on each line. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the third argument of getline to set a delimiter other than '\n'. You will use an array version of the following code:

```
string temp;
while(std::getline(file,line))
{
    std::getline(ss,temp,','); // read first value into temp and move the stream to next value

    string team(temp); 
    int a,b,c;

    ss >> a; // read the stream into a
    std::getline(ss,temp,',');  // move to next value
    ss >> b;  // read into b
    std::getline(ss,temp,','); // move to next value
    ss >> c; // read into c
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Lazarus! How do u also put each row of double numbers into their own 2d char array

Comment: Also can I use getline multiple times?

Comment: It is a bad practice to store a double number as a string. Why do you want to do that.
Yes, you can use getline multiple times, as you can see in the example.

Comment: I need to shuffle the numbers.